# Make Finder Windows Tiny

Tags: macos, finder

Is it possible to set OSX to allow tiny finder windows? The minimum window size on 10.9.5 is 452 x 294.  On a 30" monitor, 452 x 294 is still much larger than I need; wasting screen real estate. On some unix systems the window manager allows the windows to be quite small.

Is this possible on OSX? I've googled, searched Stack Exchange. I'm not finding anything.

This window would be just as useful at half it's current size:

[image: Smallest possible finder window on osx 10.9]

Answer (score 1):

Try View menu…
Hide

- Tab Bar
- Path Bar
- Status Bar
- Sidebar
- Toolbar

[image]

Doing that I can get a window down to this...
about 318 x 224

[image]